# NPM run genereate (Nuxt Fatal Error)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

При запуске приложения с локалки командой:
npm run dev
все работает нормально.
При попытке развертывания статического проекта получаю вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: в чем может быть проблема?
(компонент у меня есть в наличии - на счет которого ругается нукст.)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.
Была проблема в названии пути картинки в компоненте на который ругался нукст.